# How to handle upgrade/downgrade in iOS Auto-renew subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

Our app provides auto-renewable subscriptions to users, which deliver different content from the server based on the subscription plan.

Users can upgrade/downgrade the auto-renew subscription outside the app.
Once the user upgrades the subscription, how would the server be notified of the upgrade so it can deliver the latest content to the app?

Comment: You should periodically check the subscription (e.g every time the app launches) by getting the local receipt. A downgrade will appear as a new subscription for the lower tier at the next renewal date. An upgrade will appear as a new subscription to the higher tier immediately. You can also provide a "restore purchases" button to allow the user to manually initiate a restoration which will update the receipt.